# How can I make an onEdit() function that will watch specific columns and timestamp other specific columns?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QtBGj6FsbofJCp_Uyf8-d3IRpTL4qOWUCJ3hdmjYCxo/edit?usp=sharing

Here's a sample sheet that is much like my original, but with the main data excluded.

I need an Apps Script code that will watch the Name [B] column for an edit and timestamp the Creation [C], but I only want this to happen once. This is because in the case of someone fixing a spelling error within the name column, I don't want the date to change.

Beyond this, and the main thing I want (so in case the above isn't possible with the below, help with the below would be preferred), is for the script to watch the Sign Ups [G], Reminder [H], and Inactivity Notice [I], and Creation [C] columns for an edit, and timestamp the Updated [F] column, overwriting the previous timestamps on every edit.

## **TLDR:**

- **Exclude rows:** < 11
- **Timezone:** the timezone set on the sheet
- Multiple people will be editing the sheet.
- I do not want any timestamps to be removed, just replaced.
- I only want the function to watch the one specific sheet/tab.

## First function

- **Column to watch**: B
- **Column to timestamp:** C
- **Overwrite?:** False
- **Timestamp format:** m:d

## Second Function

- **Columns to watch:** G, H, I, C
- **Column to timestamp:** F
- **Overwrite?:** True
- **Timestamp format:** mm:dd h:mm

I've watched far too many YouTube videos, consulted a couple different AI Coding Chatbots, and spent hours just experimenting myself, but I fear I'm a little far out of my element. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I can show you how to do the first part for column B but I'm not sure what you want to do with the second part.  I leave it to you to figure out.  I've heavily consoled the function so you can check the execution log.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  console.log(e.range.getSheet().getName());
  if( e.range.getSheet().getName() === "Example" ) {  // check for the proper sheet
    console.log(e.range.getRow());
    if( e.range.getRow() > 10 ) { // check for the proper row
      console.log(e.range.getColumn());
      if( e.range.getColumn() ===  2 ) { // check for the proper column
        console.log(e.oldValue);
        if( !e.oldValue ) {  // previously empty
          let cellC = e.range.offset(0,1);
          cellC.setValue( new Date() );
          cellC.setNumberFormat("M:d");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Reference

- [onEdit(e) Event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [Sheet.Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the sheet name with your sheet name users editing speeed will be reduced and they will have to be patient and wait for the onEdit function to complete.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const idx = [7,8,9,3].indexOf(e.range.columnStart);
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.range.offset(0,1).isBlank() && e.range.rowStart != 11) {
    //e.source.toast('Gate1');
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"M/d"));
  }
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && ~idx && e.range.rowStart != 11){
    //e.source.toast('Gate2');
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,6).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM:dd HH:mm"));
  }
}
```

- [onEdit.restrictions()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)